# How to move elements from one slice to another

Tags: go, pointers, slice

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    arr0 := []int{
        1,2,3,4,5,
    }
    arr1 := []int{}

    fmt.Println(arr0)
    fmt.Println(arr1)
    fmt.Println("transferring...")
    transfer(&arr0, &arr1)
    fmt.Println(arr0)
    fmt.Println(arr1)
}

func transfer(arr0 *[]int, arr1 *[]int) {
    tmp := make([]int, 0)
    for i:=0;i<len(*arr0);i++ {
        tmp = append(tmp, (*arr0)[i])
    }

    arr1 = &tmp
    s := make([]int, 0)
    arr0 = &s
}
```

For function of transfer, I intented to transfer elements of slice arr0 to slice arr1 and empty slice arr0

But it is not successful

Here is my output

```
[1 2 3 4 5]
[]
transferring...
[1 2 3 4 5]
[]
```

After transferring, I need the result below.
[]
[1 2 3 4 5]
But actually, arr0, and arr1 in the main function remain as it was!

can someone tell me why this is not ok?

I thought in the memory, it should be like this

[image]

after running transfer function

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two lines:

```golang
arr1 = &tmp
arr0 = &s
```

change the local variables `arr1` and `arr0` within the function. Those variables happen to be pointers, but they are just copies of the input pointers provided by `main`—they are not *references* to the input pointers.

If you changed the things the `arr1` and `arr0` pointers point to, rather than the pointers themselves, then you would see a change to the values provided by `main`:

```golang
*arr1 = tmp
*arr0 = s
```

Answer (score 3):

@jacobsa has given an excellent answer.

Just keep that in mind. You can achieve the same effect but with better performance. Golang offers an excellent opportunity for this.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    arr0 := []int{
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
    }
    arr1 := []int{}

    fmt.Println(arr0)
    fmt.Println(arr1)
    fmt.Println("transferring...")
    transfer(&arr0, &arr1)
    fmt.Println(arr0)
    fmt.Println(arr1)
}

func transfer(arr0 *[]int, arr1 *[]int) {
    *arr0, *arr1 = *arr1, *arr0
}
```

Comment: Actually I want to do this
[1,2,3,4,5], [] to [], [5,4,3,2,1]
while, that is ok